# How can I make Custom Slider overlayColor different from thumbColor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

Im trying to implement a custom slider in flutter using  `SliderTheme.of(context).copywith()`, but when assigning colors to thumb and its overlay, they both becomes the same `thumbColor`.

**This is my result**

[image: Custom slider achieved]

**My code is:**

```
SliderTheme(
    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
       activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
      thumbColor: Color(0xffeb1555),
      overlayColor: Color(0x29eb1555),
      thumbShape:
          RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 10.0),
      overlayShape:
          RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20.0),
    ),
    child: Slider(
      value: height.toDouble(),
      min: 100.0,
      max: 220.0,
      divisions: 120,
      onChanged: (double newVal) {
        setState(() {
          height = newVal.toInt();
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
```

Any help welcome.
Thank you

Comment: There was simply an overlay 
thumbColor is on top of overlayColor because of their shape : thumbShape and overlayShape have same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change

```
overlayShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 20.0),
```

to

```
overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 20.0),
```

pay attention - it must be an OVERLAY shape

Comment: Oh, god. I was stubborned, couldn´t see it. Thanks!